# single cell value with given rows and columns

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have  data like this

[image]

What I want is a function giving 1 single cell value for for a given data of `row= America and column = 100` the value should be 4. So far I have created a procedure not sure if its correct (to be able to use in asp.net) I think I need function. Here it is:

```
create proc [dbo].[proc2] @productname as varchar(20), @measurement as nvarchar (20)
as
begin
select a.*, b.column_name from pro a, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b
where a.test=@productname and column_name=@measurement and b.table_name='pro'
end

exec dbo.proc2 'india',[120]
```

give me whole column.
Thank you for your help. Appreciate your time and guidance.
Sonu

Comment: You'll need to use either a CASE statement or dynamic sql

Answer (score 0):

With a stored procedure that gets the @ID_ROW and @POSITION_COLUMN parameteres :

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
(
    POSITION INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NAME SYSNAME
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 (NAME)
SELECT NAME FROM
SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(ID)= 'your table here'

SELECT @COLUMN_NAME = NAME FROM #TEMP1 WHERE POSITION=@POSITION_COLUMN

SELECT @COLUMN_NAME FROM PV3QTLOC023 WHERE 
ROW = @ID_ROW
```

Comment: The OP is passing the column_name into the procedure. Why would they also need that as an output.

Comment: Hi J i managed to create temp table but getting error messg when inserting into are you able to explain in more detail please.